# replaceAll("match","replace") in java

Tags: java, regex

is there any efficient way to do multiple replaceAll("match","replace").

I'm finding match using regex and replace.
e.g.

```
public static String replacePattern(String line)
{
 if(line != null || !"".equals(line)) 
  {
    line = line.replaceAll("regexPattern_1","replacce_1");
    line = line.replaceAll("regexPattern_2","replacce_2"); 
    line = line.replaceAll("regexPattern_3","replacce_3");
    line = line.replaceAll("regexPattern_4","replacce_4");

    .
    .
    .
    line = line.replaceAll("regexPattern_N","replacce_N");
    return line;
  }
 return line;
}
```

I don't want code look good, to me Perf is important

Comment: There are shorter ways of writing the code sure, but not really any more efficient way of doing, at least not noteworthy so. Think, like a computer, of how many comparisons are needed to do it.

Comment: For ALL cases? Probably not. Depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: Just place the pattern-replace pairs in a HashMap and write a loop

Comment: @leonbloy That's not really more efficient, which is what he asked about. But I agree it looks cleaner

Comment: Is scenario like `replaceAll("a","b")` and then `replaceAll("b","c")` possible? What result would you want to achieve for input like `abc`? Should it be `bcc` or `ccc`?

Comment: don't you think `replaceAll` will inspect the whole string every time and that will affect the time taken to perform the task. It's always better to combine the multiple regex expression in single and calling `replaceAll` just once. In the end it depends on your specific requirement if not possible to club in single regex expression.

Comment: @Pshemo not like that i dont wan replace abc to bcc not ccc. i wan replace a to a1 or b to b1 and so on.

Comment: each replace case is diff. i need to replace "abc" to "a1b1c1" if match found

Comment: This snippet doesn't show core of the problem. Non regex replace is (sometimes) many, many times quicker than regex.

Comment: @hiteshghuge have you solved your problem?

Comment: @pooya: Existing was works fine, i was looking for faster way to do this....                and b'coz im using to many replaceAll() at a time my code look very dirty

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by shorter but if you want shorter texts to write you can use:

```
line = line.replaceAll("regexPattern_1","replacce_1")
           .replaceAll("regexPattern_2","replacce_2") 
           .replaceAll("regexPattern_3","replacce_3")
           .replaceAll("regexPattern_4","replacce_4")
           .
           .
           .
           .replaceAll("regexPattern_N","replacce_N");
```

Or:

```
String[] patterns = new String[] {"pattern1",....};
String[]  replace = new String[] {"replace1",....};

for(int i=0; i<patterns.length; i++)
{
   line = line.replaceAll(patterns[i],replace[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **Strings** are immutable another way to handle this:

```
str.replaceAll("a", "b").replaceAll("c", "d").replaceAll("e", "f");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether efficiency could be improved. But you can make it look good. If you want more elegance, you can use recursion which will need some additional work for termination.

```
public static String replacePattern(String line)
{
  //intitialize String[] repl with items to be replaces
  //initialize String[] pattern with corresponding replacements
  for(int i = 0; i<repl.length; i++)
     if(line != null || !"".equals(line)) 
        line = line.replaceAll(repl[i],pattern[i]);

 return line;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by recursion?

Comment: Recursively passing line, arrays replacement strings, array of pattern strings, position parameter. Use position parameter to build a base case

Comment: not a good solution for this case which can be solved with one line for loop

Comment: Yeah. I just mentioned that it is possible and will look elegant.